# Convert / translate t-sql query to MS Access query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL query that I want to use in MS Access, but I can't get it right. Any help would be apprecitated.

```
select tblKPIData.Id
     , tblKPIData.KPI_id
     , tblKPIData.Quantity
     , tblKPIData.FinancialMonth
     , tblKPIData.FinancialYear
     , tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp 
     , tblDashboadKPI.Dashboard_Id
from (
    select tblKPIData.kpi_id,
           max(tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp) as ImportTimestamp
    from tblKPIData
    group by tblKPIData.KPI_id
)
as b
inner join tblKPIData
on tblKPIData.KPI_id = b.KPI_id 
and tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp = b.ImportTimestamp
right join tblDashboadKPI
on tblDashboadKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id
where FinancialMonth = 'nov'
and FinancialYear = 2016
and tblDashboadKPI.Dashboard_Id = 5
order by tblKPIData.Id
        ,tblKPIData.KPI_id
```

Comment: where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If your query currently works, I would suggest:

```
select kp.Id, kp.KPI_id, kp.Quantity, kp.FinancialMonth,
       kp.FinancialYear, kp.ImportTimestamp,
       d.Dashboard_Id
from ((select tblKPIData.kpi_id,
              max(tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp) as ImportTimestamp
       from tblKPIData
       group by tblKPIData.KPI_id
      ) as b inner join
      tblKPIData as kp
      on kp.KPI_id = b.KPI_id and kp.ImportTimestamp = b.ImportTimestamp
     ) right join
     tblDashboadKPI as d
     on d.KPI_Id = kp.KPI_id
where FinancialMonth = "nov" and FinancialYear = 2016 and
      d.Dashboard_Id = 5
order by kp.Id, kp.KPI_id;
```

Changes:

- `JOIN`s need to have additional parentheses
- Strings uses double quots
- I introduced table aliases as well, to simplify the query

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the solution:

```
SELECT tblKPIData.Id
     , tblKPIData.KPI_id
     , tblKPIData.Quantity
     , tblKPIData.FinancialMonth
     , tblKPIData.FinancialYear
     , tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp
     , tblKPIData.Type
     , tblDashboadKPI.Dashboard_Id
FROM tblDashboadKPI
INNER JOIN tblKPIData 
ON tblDashboadKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id
WHERE (((tblKPIData.FinancialMonth)="nov") 
         AND ((tblKPIData.FinancialYear)=2016) 
         AND ((tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp)=(select max(d2.ImportTimestamp) 
                                            from tblKPIData as d2
                                            where d2.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_Id)) 
         AND ((tblDashboadKPI.Dashboard_Id)=5));
```

Thanx for your help!